# Just a entrance alone will continue a lot of people entrance adult to recreate

Tags: meaning

“Just a entrance alone will continue a lot of people entrance adult to recreate,” pronounced Manager Gary Lamb. (http://boston-massachusetts.us/conservation-plan-also-brings-development-in-maine)

Gary Lamb uttered a totally incomprehensible sentence, at least for  a not native of English language: it seem as the grammatical meaning, which is signaled by the structure words, is not present.

Please, help me in understanding that sentence.

Comment: Too Localised. I've no idea what Lamb might *actually* have said, but it clearly got garbled. Trying to decipher the original isn't really worth it.

Comment: You have unfortunately found an incorrect transcription. The original is "*[Just the access alone will perpetuate a lot of people coming up to recreate," said Manager Gary Lamb.](http://www.necn.com/05/15/12/Conservation-plan-also-brings-developmen/landing_business.html?blockID=708524&feedID=4209)*" which is unobjectionable.

Comment: @MarkBeadles - Yes. Tjhe transcription is purposefully altered  - presumably to notionally prevent it violating copyright. It's a serach engine honeypot to generate advertising revenue. There are some very unworthwhile people abusing the interenet, alas. Some people aggregate references which at leasts attempt to be pertinent but sites like this rely on poor copying.

Answer (score 4):

The term is complete rubbish - it is not English.
The sentence was generated by a computer with the aim of making money.

The site cited is a rubbish site whose content was generated by a computer which searched the internet for material to reproduce in a manner which is scrambled enough that it does not violate copyright, but which hopes to make the site look legitimate to search engines.

The aim is to  attract search engines by using words that people may search for, in the hope of generating advertising "click throughs" and making money.

Hopefully search engine algorithm writers will be on average smarter than the miscreants who produce such sites.

Comment: [This appears to be the original article](http://www.necn.com/05/15/12/Conservation-plan-also-brings-developmen/landing_business.html?blockID=708524&feedID=4209).

Comment: "perpetuate a lot of people coming up to recreate" kind of reminds me of the command in Genesis to "be fruitful and multiply".